# Есть 2 карты google maps в табах (одна страница) при переходе слитают

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-maps-api, google-maps

Есть табы, при переходе между ними слетает карта (серая) при изменении окна браузера - начинает работать. Помогите решить проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При переключении табов, можно вызвать событие на объекте

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
```

[google api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1) » Events

Comment: спасибо +1 балл, бро!

Answer (score 0):

Может кому пригодится

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function()  { 
    $('#myModal1').click(function() { 
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); 
    });
    $('#myModal2').click(function() { 
      google.maps.event.trigger(map1, 'resize'); 
    });     
  }); 
</script>
```